# Scope resolution operator if three variables exist

Tags: c++, scope

I just started learning c++. I came across scope resolution operator and I tried a program something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i = 40;
int main(){
    int i = 20;
    {  
        int i = 10;
        cout<< ::i;  // prints 40
        cout<<i;    // prints 10
        cout << i;  // how do i print variable i whose value is 20 
    }
}
```

But if i want to access the variable i ( i=20) inside the inner block of `main()`. How do i do that? is it possible? This may be stupid but I am not aware of all the built in functions of c++. So wanted to find out if theres any way to do it. Thanks

Comment: I don't imagine this is possible.

Comment: I imagine this is impossible.

Comment: There are very few cases when you want to shadow a variable like this. In those few cases, there are absolutely zero when you also want to refer to the outer variable. So that's why this isn't possible.

Comment: Why write code that on a first glance is ambiguous? Just use sensible names for variables and avoid possible confusion in the future.

Comment: Possible or not, but very interesting.

Comment: @jrok I have answered this using different approach. Is it a valid approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using `namespaces`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace inner{int i;}
int i = 40;
int main() {
    inner::i = 20;
    {
        int i = 10;
        cout<< ::i;  // prints 40
        cout<<i;    // prints 10
        cout << inner::i; // this prints 20
    }
}
```

I hope this can be used for several `i`'s in a code.

**EDIT** The answer changes the program semantically as it makes inner `i` a global variable.

Comment: this changes the semantics of the program, though, `inner::i` is now global where it was local before.

Comment: should i consider to remove the answer? @StephenLin

Comment: probably, all it can do it confuse